# Macro to sync active item in Solution Navigator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't like the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option in VS, since it seems to slow things down a lot, and can be a bit buggy.

Instead, I'm using the macro shown here (http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2008/04/30/locating-the-active-item-in-solution-explorer.aspx) to manually sync the solution explorer using a shortcut key.

Now, I'm switching from using Solution Explorer to the new Solution Navigator that comes with the VS Productivity Pack, and I'm missing this functionality a lot.

Does anyone know if there's anything I can do to manually sync the Solution Navigator to the active item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has this built-in using the SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument command (default key binding is Ctrl+[, Ctrl+S

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this, as the Solution Navigator has an "Open" tab that shows all open files?

Comment: No - this is not what I want.  I want to see the open file highlighted in the folder hierarchy.